# How to create an excel report by month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of data in excel with a date column. When I want to generate a report I typically create a new column in the *data* tab and type in a code in text format like "April08", then I put a hidden column on the *report* tab with that code and use a sumif formula to add up the quantities  in the column matching the "April08" Is there an easier way to do this in Excel?

Comment: >type in a code in text format like "April08". A bit confused.  You type this once, or once for every entry that has xx/04/2008 in the date column (or 04/xx/2008 in USian)

Comment: try looking into Access, there is the ability to have "one-click" reports generated in nice formats. Might be a bit more complex than what you were looking for, but I think you'll find Access has a lot of reporting possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `SUMIFS` function, you can specify multiple criteria. So

```
=SUMIFS(data!B:B, data!A:A, ">="&startDate, data!A:A, "<="&endDate)
```

where column B in the `data` worksheet contains the data you want to sum, and column A contains the dates. `startDate` and `endDate` are named ranges with your start and end dates (in this example they would contain 1 Apr 2008 and 30 April 2008 respectively). Obviously you don't have to use named ranges; I've just put that in for clarity.

Alternatively, use a 'helper' column as you have, but put a formula in it instead of manually typing "April08" etc. Something like `=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1)` would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what version you are using or exactly how your data is laid out, but using a pivot table is a powerful tool to present the information how you want from the list of data.

If you aren't familiar with pivot tables, here is an excellent tutorial - [Excel Pivot Tables Tutorial : What is a Pivot Table and How to Make one](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/19/excel-pivot-tables-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use array formulas to get the sum you want without having to add a helper column, like so:

```
=SUM((MONTH(dates)=4)*(YEAR(dates)=2008)*sales)
```

(see formula A in my example below)

*Where:*

`dates` -- the range that contains your dates  (column A in my example below)
`sales` -- the range that contains the stuff you want to add up (column B in my example below)
`4` and `2008` refers to my target month and year, in this case, anything that falls within April 2008.

**Example:**

[image]

This formula should also give you the same result (formula B above):

```
=SUM((TEXT(dates,"mmm yyyy")="Apr 2008")*sales)
```

Just change it to suit your spreadsheet.

*Don't forget to commit the formulas using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.*

Comment: Wow that is incredibly useful- I can't believe I've been wasting so much time the way I've been doing things.