# SUMIF by category and date in range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a table where I keep a transaction log of expenditures as so (excerpt)

```
Date    Paid    Purpose
```

where the date is the date when the transaction is conducted, Paid is the actual amount paid and Purpose is an item from a column in a table in the same worksheet.

The log runs across different months and different years as well, what I am trying to achieve on a different page is a total by month for specific category in a particular year like so:

```
               May-2012    Jun-2012    Jul-2012   etc
Purpose 1
Purpose 2
Purpose 3
```

I am more confused by what I'm seeing online and have not yet edged to an answer.  All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is what you want,

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

set `B13` to

```
=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$10, $A$2:$A$10, ">="&B$12, $A$2:$A$10, "<"&(EOMONTH(B$12,0)+1),
                            $C$2:$C$10, "="&$A13)
```

and drag/fill.

<sub>Edit:</sub>

---

#### General explanation of `SUMIFS` (excerpted) from Excel’s online help:

> #### Description
>
> Adds the cells in a [range](https://superuser.com/a/601478/150988) that meet multiple criteria.  For example, if you want to sum the numbers in the range A1:A20 only if the corresponding numbers in B1:B20 are greater than zero (0) and the corresponding numbers in C1:C20 are less than 10, you can use the following formula:
>
> `=SUMIFS(A1:A20, B1:B20, ">0", C1:C20, "<10")`
>
> #### Syntax
>
> `SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], …)`

#### Specific explanation of my answer:

- `$B$2:$B$10` –– is the data you want to sum
- `$A$2:$A$10, ">="&B$12` –– where the date (from Column `A` in the first part of the sheet) is on or after the first of the month in the heading of this column (`B`) in the second part of the sheet, and
- `$A$2:$A$10, "<"&(EOMONTH(B$12,0)+1)` –– the date is before (less than) the first day of the following month (i.e., the last day (“end of”) this month, plus one), and
- `$C$2:$C$10, "="&$A13` –– the purpose (from Column `C` in the first part of the sheet) is the same as the purpose in the first column (`A`) in this row.

Comment: Note my little trick for making answers easier to understand: by using powers of two as my source data, I allow each result to be uniquely reversible.  For example, 20 can only be 4+16, and 192 can only be 64+128.

Comment: Thanks, this is EXACTLY what I want!  Can I ask you to please explain the SUMIF command as it is used here?

Comment: I have found another solution which might be regarded as a little more elegant.  (I “found” it in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/566089/150988).)  `=SUM((TEXT($A$2:$A$9,"mmm yyyy")=TEXT(B$12,"mmm yyyy"))*($C$2:$C$9=$A13)*$B$2:$B$9)`.  It is an array formula, so you must type (Ctrl)+(Shift)+(Enter) when you enter it.

Comment: I was doing it like this: `=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$999999,$A$3:$A$999999, ">="&DATE(2021,1,1), $A$3:$A$999999, "<="&EOMONTH(DATE(2020,12,1),1))`, but it would not allow me to drag to fill. so i had to modify the `DATE()` values one by one. any idea why that might be? is it because im not depending on dates in cells?

Comment: @oldboy If you provide some details, you *might* get a response.  Where did you put the formula?  What happened when you tried to drag/fill? “it would not allow me” is too vague.  What did you do to debug it, and what were the results?  For good measure, what version of Excel are you using, and can you identify any other factors that might be relevant?

Comment: Sorry! By 'it would not allow me to drag fill', what I meant was that the `DATE` values were not updating upon dragging the formula to other cells. I wrote the formula in specific cells and then tried dragging to other relevant cells. Unfortunately, I am using 2010 Home and Student, so perhaps this is the culprit?

Comment: Well, I still don’t understand. What were you expecting to happen? Something like `DATE(2020,12,1)` acts like any other expression with only constant terms, like ``=5+12`` or even ``17`` — it’s not going to change when you drag it. Only relative (i.e., non-absolute) cell references get auto-updated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert your data into an Excel Table (Insert>Table, check the header box)
2. Select a cell in your new Table and create a Pivot Table (Insert>Pivot Table)
3. Organize the Pivot Table:

   - Column Labels = Date (can be grouped at whatever level you like, e.g. month)
   - Row Labels = Purpose
   - Values = Paid (formated to your local currency)

[image: Pivot Example]